# seems your device does not support camera on nexus phone

Tags: android, opencv

My project working fine on Galaxy s2 but on my nexus phone my open cv project is not running. The tutorial provided by open cv is running but some how it seems my project is not running and nexus is saying "It seems that you device does not support camera(or it is locked). Application will be closed. Can some one give some idea how to get rid of it .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Nexus tablet? you might be trying to access a specific camera in your code (i.e you might be trying to access back camera in nexus tablet) which does not exist.
Something like this will not work in nexus 7 tablet(older nexus 7 version)

```
cv::VideoCapture capture(CV_CAP_ANDROID + 0);
```

Comment: HI, i am not using nexus 7 table. I am using nexus 4. I tried this but it does not seems working.

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem with nexus 4 and kit kat (4.4). OpenCV doesn't support native camera for this system yet - try Java camera version instead, it should works.

EDIT:

If you want to solve this problem (I assume you have 4.4 Android) you have to rebuild camera_wrapper using Android OS sources. That's the way until next OpenCV official release.

Comment: HI, But some how the tutorial provided by open cv is working so it seems their is something wrong in my code only and no nexus device works.

Comment: Did you check if in your application and in tutorial is using the same version of CameraBridge? I mean native and java versions.